# When New Note button is clicked it won't pop up Form. Can't figure out whats missing

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router, components, crud

I attached the code for my form component and my notes component. Tryed clicking on New button but form won't pop up or console.log anythingimport React from "react";

```
 function NoteForm() {
  console.log("Form");
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="title"></input>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NoteForm;


import React from "react";
import { deleteNote } from "../CRUD/noteFunction.js";
import NoteForm from "./noteForm.js";

function Notes({ Note }) {
  return (
    <main className="page">
      <h2 className="page__title">Notes</h2>
      <button onClick={() => { return <NoteForm />}} className="btn--gray">
        NEW NOTE +
      </button>
    </main>
  );
}

export default Notes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually rendering NoteForm.
Do something similar to this,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { deleteNote } from "../CRUD/noteFunction.js";
import NoteForm from "./noteForm.js";

function Notes({ Note }) {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);

  const handleNewNoteClick = () => {
    setShowForm(true);
  };

  return (
    <main className="page">
      <h2 className="page__title">Notes</h2>
      <button onClick={handleNewNoteClick} className="btn--gray">
        NEW NOTE +
      </button>
      {showForm && <NoteForm />}
    </main>
  );
}

export default Notes;
```